# Bluetooth chat between mobile and pc

Tags: java, bluetooth, chat

Is it possible to create a application that create (text) chat session between pc and mobile over bluetooth,
Which stack is best for this, and which language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  It is not very hard.  However it depends on the mobile it depends on the level of bluetooth suppport.  Usually mobiles come with only one stack.  For the PC sometimes you have a choice of stack, but I suggest using either Microsoft or Widcomm since these are most popular and usually come bundled with the devices.   Same for the language use whatever you are most comfortable with and whatever has the best support.

However, why would you want such in app to begin with.  Bluetooth range is rather limited,  and usually instead of using the chat app you can just talk.